# Getting Value of Header with Min()/Max() in Excel

Tags: excel, indexing, excel-formula, match, lookup

I would like to calculate the minimum of some values. Beside this I want to catch the value of the "Minimum" header.
Example:

```
+------------+----------+--------+------+--------+
|     A      |    B     |   C    |  D   | result |
+------------+----------+--------+------+--------+
| item       | New York | Boston | Phil | ---    |
| Apple      | 3.4      | 4.2    | 2.3  | Phil   |
| Peach      | 2.2      | 2.5    | 1.7  | Phil   |
| Strawberry | 5.5      | 5.1    | 7.3  | Boston |
+------------+----------+--------+------+--------+
```

I can find the MIN() in the row 'Apple'. But how can i manage to receive the column header as a result like Phil in this example?

Comment: INDEX/MATCH should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `INDEX` + `AGGREGATE`:

```
=INDEX($B$1:$D$1;AGGREGATE(14;6;(B2:D2=MIN(B2:D2))*COLUMN(B2:D2)-1;1))
```

[image]

Comment: The short way round would be `=INDEX($1:$1,MATCH(MIN(A2:D2),A2:D2,0))` =)

Comment: Yes, this is a better option. Add an answer.

Comment: Thanks. It is woking. :)